# A hrefs in slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I used this slideshow http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/2/ and made few changes -> http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/386/

But I need two things:

1) Pagination - I need link from pagination to appropriate image.

2) If you go from last to first image and from first to last you will see just white space.

**Code of old version**

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/0000CD&text=1" width="500" height="100" alt="first image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/008000&text=2" width="500" height="100" alt="second image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/B22222&text=3" width="500" height="100" alt="third image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100/F4A460&text=4" width="500" height="100" alt="fourth image">
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    /* necessary to absolutely position the images inside */
    width: 500px;
    /* same as the images inside */
    height: 100px;
}
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
    display: block;
    /* overrides the previous style */
}
```

JS:

```
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(getNext, 2000); // milliseconds
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.slideshow img').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
        $next.css('z-index', 1);
    });

}
```

**New version**

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="arrow-left" id="prev"></div>
    <img src="http://www.theextramilewithcharlie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/MovingTargetMobile_f2.jpg" width="360" height="222" alt="Yellow" class="slide">
    <img src="https://www.digitec.ch/img/t-1-64-E8454026A2BFADCFE29E820F854838F4/disk2go-usb-stick-nano-16gb-usb-20-red-usb-flash-drive.png" width="360" height="222" alt="Red" class="slide">
    <img src="https://www.digitec.ch/img/t-1-64-605CE6EB9472BEB7A267A29F5F052D6B/kef-c6lcr-black-center-speaker-hifi-homecinema-speaker.png" width="360" height="222" alt="Black" class="slide">
    <img src="http://www.qishop.cyklomax.cz/RM-14-Cross-100-18-black-blue-white-_a45681105_10639.aspx?fm=0&width=360" width="360" height="222" alt="Blue" class="slide">
<div class="arrow-right" id="next"></div>

<div class="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 280px;">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    /* necessary to absolutely position the images inside */
    width: 500px;
    /* same as the images inside */
    height: 100px;
}
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
    display: block;
    /* overrides the previous style */
}
.arrow-left{
    float:left;
    width:15px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrowhover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:auto;
}

.arrow-left:hover{
    background:url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.arrow-right{
    float:right;
    width:15px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrowhover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:auto;
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-right:hover{
    background:url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.pagination{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:3px;
}

.yellow{
    display:inline-block;
    width:54px;
    height:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#ffd631;
}

.yellow:hover{
    height:7px !important;
}

.red{
    display:inline-block;
    width:54px;
    height:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#ff5e5e;
}

.red:hover{
    height:7px !important;
}

.black{
    display:inline-block;
    width:54px;
    height:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#3b3b3b;
}

.black:hover{
    height:7px !important;
}

.blue{
    display:inline-block;
    width:54px;
    height:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#52708a;
}

.blue:hover{
    height:7px !important;
}
```

JS is same.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things:

- The slideshow div's completion tag did not balance.
- The navigation (left/right) buttons were part of the slideshow div, which is why you got the blank entry - it was the navigation button.
- The left button was hidden, so I moved it out the slideshow div and added offset it by 20px.
- There was no link to the page navigation. You had the class names in alt, but I think it is better not to use the `alt` attribute, since this is for accessibility. Instead, I used a data-linked-class attribute. I also added an `indicatePage` class to the CSS to toggle the height on or off.
- The interval was not being reissued, so it would only cycle once. A timer is probably a more appropriate choice here, where you reissue the timer with each transition. I have left it as an interval for the moment.
- Not sure why the page links grew on hover. If you want to go the appropriate page, then you can do a similar change to what I did for showing the page link, but in reverse.

You can fade the addClass / removeClass transition using animations if you want the page link to fade in / out as well.

***Update based on comment***

- Added class 'nav', changed color classes to id.
- Linked back to img in function in $.ready()
- Cancelled interval if not a timer driven event, which is what I think you want to do.

```js
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    getNext(null, true);
  }, 2000); // milliseconds
  $('#next').on('click', getNext);
  $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);
  $('.nav').click(function() {
    var $next = $('img[data-linked-id=' + this.id + ']');
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible');
    transition($curr, $next, false);
  });
});

function getNext(event, keepInterval) {
  var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();

  transition($curr, $next, keepInterval);
}

function getPrev() {
  var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.slideshow img').last();
  transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next, keepInterval) {
  if (!keepInterval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
    $next.css('z-index', 1);
    $('#' + $curr.attr('data-linked-id')).removeClass('indicatePage');
    $('#' + $next.attr('data-linked-id')).addClass('indicatePage');
  });
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  /* necessary to absolutely position the images inside */
  width: 500px;
  /* same as the images inside */
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
.slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
  display: block;
  /* overrides the previous style */
}
.arrow-left {
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrowhover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
.arrow-left:hover {
  background: url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.arrow-right {
  float: right;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrowhover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.arrow-right:hover {
  background: url(http://eshop.lukasholeczy.eu/images/arrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.pagination {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 3px;
}
#yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffd631;
}
#yellow:hover {
  height: 7px !important;
}
#red {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ff5e5e;
}
#red:hover {
  height: 7px !important;
}
#black {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #3b3b3b;
}
#black:hover {
  height: 7px !important;
}
#blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #52708a;
}
#blue:hover {
  height: 7px !important;
}
.indicatePage {
  height: 7px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow-left" id="prev"></div>
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="http://www.theextramilewithcharlie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/MovingTargetMobile_f2.jpg" width="360" height="222" data-linked-id='yellow' alt="Yellow" class="slide" />
  <img src="https://www.digitec.ch/img/t-1-64-E8454026A2BFADCFE29E820F854838F4/disk2go-usb-stick-nano-16gb-usb-20-red-usb-flash-drive.png" width="360" height="222" alt="Red" data-linked-id='red' class="slide" />
  <img src="https://www.digitec.ch/img/t-1-64-605CE6EB9472BEB7A267A29F5F052D6B/kef-c6lcr-black-center-speaker-hifi-homecinema-speaker.png" width="360" height="222" alt="Black" data-linked-id='black' class="slide" />
  <img src="http://www.qishop.cyklomax.cz/RM-14-Cross-100-18-black-blue-white-_a45681105_10639.aspx?fm=0&width=360" width="360" height="222" alt="Blue" data-linked-id='blue' class="slide" />
</div>
<div class="arrow-right" id="next"></div>
<div class="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 280px;">
  <div id="yellow" class="nav"></div>
  <div id="red" class="nav"></div>
  <div id="black" class="nav"></div>
  <div id="blue" class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are just amazing, thank you. And one last thing, how can I do navigation clickable?

Comment: @KarelPoláček see my update. Please upvote if helpful or accept if the answer that you were looking for.

Comment: @KarelPoláček - to avoid confusion I removed the fiddle example, so it is the one inline in my answer.

Comment: Totally helpful, thank you! 

// I haven't reputation for up-vote, sorry.